# How to communicate from a Python client to Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am to develop an app, and I have to choose between `Ruby on Rails` or `Python+Django`. So far I want to do it with `Ruby on Rails`, because i feel more comfortable doing what I have to do on it.

But there is a problem. There would be a client app written on `Python` that has to communicate with mine. Cause that app should be able to communicate with mine.

**First:** I think if it is a matter of communicating with the `MySQL` database there wouldn't be an issue, cause the `Python` app is able to query to `MySQL` server with proper authentication right?

**Second:** and more important question: If I have a `Ruby` written API, to ease the queries, Could the `Python` app be able to invoke functions in that API and get the results? If it is possible, How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails 5 supports API only app, if you are using this app for APIs only, else just create a normal app and expose API endpoints that render `json` outputs. Use `Active Record` for mapping your MySql database and `jbuilder` for json views (both of which are available by default when you create new app). You will find lots of tutorials if you google `Use Ruby on Rails as API app`.

Good luck with it.. :)

Comment: I am not using this app for an API only, it is a web app with a front-end. Could I include an API module for its functions to be invoked from python (how to?) or just ask the python app to query the database directly?

Comment: yes, create an `API` namespace module and routes, e.g. you want to get details for user with ID 1, your route will be `domain/api/v1/user/1`, now this will go to `users#show` query the database and spit out the results in json `{ id:1, fname: 'foo', lname: 'bar'...`. This way your python app don't need to connect with db at all and will be a basic client app only(i would recommend this) with all business logic in rails app only

Comment: short answer: a JSON based RESTful api that is exposed via http calls. It turns out that this is a fairly lightweight bit of work and relies on common technologies (JSON & HTTP in this case) to let two separate technologies communicate. This is really basically what the answerer says, but when I heard it phrased this way it made more sense to me.